# Write a program in C++ that sums a simple series: 1/N + 2/N-1 + 3/N-2+ … N/1

Tags: c++, loops, sum

I have been tasked to write a program that computes the series mentioned in the title. Everything seems to work just fine in the program, but the equation is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double n;
  double sum = 0;

  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> n;

  for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    sum = (1 / i) + (2 / i - 1) + (3 / i - 2);
  }

  cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *Everything seems to work just fine in the program, but the equation is wrong.* Only one of these can be true.

Comment: Ask yourself how are you going to get the term `4 / N - 3` with what you have.

Comment: Write down the series for, say, N = 4: 1/4 + 2/3 + 3/2 + 4/1. Then compare to what your program is doing. (Step through the entire loop by hand.)

Comment: Do you know how to interpret _1/N + 2/N-1 + 3/N-2+ … N/1_? If not, then you should start with that.

Comment: Every time someone says "sum" I can't help thinking [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in your equation. First, each iteration saves a **new** value into sum which is not what you want. Second, where is the rest of the series? And why are you storing only the first three elements into sum?

I would suggest using this code instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      double n;
      double sum = 0;

      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> n;

      for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      {
        sum += i / (n-i+1);
      }

      cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

This way, sum starts with a zero and adds one element of the series to the overall sum at each iteration, starting with 1/n, then 1/n + 2/(n-1) and so on.